# To use a variable created in one javascript file to be used in a node file and another angular file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a variable declared in config.js file. I'm trying to use this variable in a node file using "require" `var isro_debug = require('./config.js');

Here's the variable:

```
module.exports = { isro_debug:true };
```

I tried using this variable in another angular file by providing the paths of config.js and the file in which I want to use the variable in a html file using script tags like this:

```
<script src="/home/karthik/iwm/ui/VLNodeFrontEnd/config.js"></script>
<script src="file2.js"></script>
```

When I'm trying to execute the code errors are showing up. Can somebody please help me with this?

Comment: Can you please provide your directory listing/setup (with just the relevant files) and the specific errors you're getting? Also, please add an example of how you are trying to reference the needed variable.

Answer (score 0):

`module.exports = { isro_debug:true };` is a [CommonJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS) syntax. It is only recognized by node, but not by the browser, so when you add it to your html via a `script` tag, the browser tries to parse it and fails.

You need to use a tool like [browserify](http://browserify.org/) to transpile the file to a syntax that the browser knows.

Comment: Could you please help me in finding a solution which doesn't involve using browserify?

Comment: there is no other solution, either you 'compile' the file, or you create another file for the browser where you define the same variable again as `window.isro_debug=true`